# ubuntu 18.04 how to install over a bonded interface

Tags: network-bonding

Is it possible to install ubuntu server over a bonded interface. Trying to see if i can pass bond information as boot params and configure bonding ? Any example would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: Why would it need to be bonded during install?

Comment: network switch is configured with lacp. Interfaces won't show as active unless they are bonded during install or reinstall. For centos /rhel i can pass bond as a boot parameter with the bonded interfaces. on ubuntu, this is not supported or not working . I get my kickstart / preseed file over the network so need to network to be up to pull the initial  config file.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?